# CombinedPropertyError Discord.js v14

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm using Discord.js Version 14, there's a problem about the embeds, I know the .addField doesn't exist anymore, now it's .addFields I saw in the docs how the command is but it's still having an error!
Just for the record I'm Brazilian so the command will be in Portuguese!
The command:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const ms = require("moment")


module.exports = {

    name: "channelinfo",
    description : "｢│ Utilidades｣ Veja a informação dos canais",
    type: Discord.ApplicationCommandType.ChatInput,
options: [
       {
            name: "canal",
            description: "O canal onde quer pesquisar",
            type: Discord.ApplicationCommandOptionType.Channel,
            required: true
        }
    ],
        run : async (client, interaction, args) => { 

let channel = interaction.options.getChannel("canal")
 const canalType = {
            "GuildVoice": "Canal de voz",
   "GuildText": "Canal de Texto",
   "GuildNews": "Canal de Anúncios",
   "GuildPublicThread": "Canal de tópico",
   "GuildPrivateThread": "Canal de tópico privado",
   "GuildStageVoice": "Canal de palco",
   "GuildNewsThread": "Canal de tópico",
   "GuildCategory": "Categoria"
 }
          const canalImagem = {
              "GuildVoice": "https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/980553631310942210/996121146258890942/ChannelVC.png",
   "GuildText": "https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/980553631310942210/996121146778996806/Icon_ChannelText.png",
   "GuildNews": "https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/980553631310942210/996121147248738384/ChannelAnnouncements.png",
   "GuildPublicThread": "https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/980553631310942210/996121146506363051/ChannelThread.png",
   "GuildPrivateThread": "https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/980553631310942210/996121897278394490/ChannelPrivate.png",
   "GuildNewsThread": "https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/980553631310942210/996122135036694610/ChannelAnnouncementThread.png",
         "GuildStageVoice": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/829073837538410556.png",
            "GuildCategory": "https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/980553631310942210/996166403696644116/ChannelCategory.png"
          }
          yesno = {
            "true": "Sim",
            "false": "Não"
          }
                let topic = interaction.channel.topic ? interaction.channel.topic : 'Sem descrição';
    const channelinfo = new Discord.EmbedBuilder()
    
    .setTitle(`${channel.name || `${channel.parent.name}`}`)
    .setColor("#BABABA")
    .setThumbnail(canalImagem[channel.type])
    .addFields({name: `${client.emoji.channel} Nome do Canal`, value: `${channel.name || `${channel.parent.name}`} `, inline: true},
  {name: `${client.emoji.id} ID do Canal`, value: `\`${channel.id}\``, inline: true},
{name: `${client.emoji.clock} Criado no dia:`, value: `<t:${~~(channel.createdAt / 1000)}:f>`, inline: true },
{name: `${client.emoji.channel} Tipo de Canal`, value: canalType[channel.type] /*.`${channel.type}`*/, inline: true},
              )
if (channel.parent){channelinfo.addFields({name: `${client.emoji.category} Categoria do Canal`, value: `${channel.parent?.name || "Sem categoria"}`, inline: true})
  if (channel.topic)  {                   channelinfo.spliceFields({name: `Descrição do canal`, value: `${topic}`, inline: true})
}     
       if (channel.rateLimitPerUser)   {   channelinfo.spliceFields(3, 0, {name: 'Modo Lento', value: `${channel.rateLimitPerUser}`, inline: true}) }
        if (channel.nsfw)    {    channelinfo.spliceFields(6, 0, {name: 'NSFW', value: yesno[channel.nsfw], inline: true})
        }  
          if (channel.type === 'GuildVoice') {
             channelinfo // Voice embed
                .spliceFields(5, 0, {name: 'Limite de usuários', value: `${channel.userLimit}`, inline: true})
                .spliceFields(6, 0, {name: 'Canal cheio', value: yesno[channel.full], inline: true})
            }
    interaction.reply({embeds: [channelinfo]})

  } 
}
            }
```

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OH3af.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the code you posted is from `/home/runner/      /slash/Info/channelinfo.js`.
The error says that the problem is at Line 51, Column 6. I think this is the code on line 51 (**if it's not, please respond with what you have on that line**):

```js
f (channel.parent){channelinfo.addFields({name: `${client.emoji.category} Categoria do Canal`, value: `${channel.parent?.name || "Sem categoria"}`, inline: true})
```

You have a syntax error near `channel.parent.name`. There seems to be a rogue question mark.

Next time, please copy-paste the error in code fences so that it is easy for others to copy.
Hope this helped.